# can't run compass after installing rvm

Tags: ruby, sass, rvm, compass-sass

I installed RVM yesterday and now I can't run Compass, I get the following error.

```
compass watch skin/frontend/default/default/
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'compass' (>= 0) among 13 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/compass:22:in `<main>'
```

I guess I need to update my compass and/or sass config?  But I'm not sure how.

```
$ which -a gem
/Users/holy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/gem
/usr/bin/gem
```

Answer (score 0):

have tried reinstalling sass and compass ? Sorry for the probably obvious answer

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just set RVM to use the system Ruby and Compass worked again, the command is:

```
rvm use system
```